# NSIS takes ownership of IIS system files

Tags: iis-7, uac, nsis, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I recently encountered an issue with NSIS that I believe is related to an interaction with UAC, but I am at a loss to explain it and I do not know how to prevent it in the future.

I have an installer that creates and removes IIS virtual directories using the NsisIIS plugin.  The installer appeared worked correctly on my Windows 7 workstation.  When the installer was run on a Windows 2008 R2 server it installed properly, but the uninstaller removed all of the virtual directories and put IIS is an unusable state; to the point that I had to remove the Default Web Site and re-add it.

What I eventually found was that all of the IIS configuration files under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` had a lock icon on them.

[image: Screenshot of IIS config files after NSIS runs]

Some [investigation](http://www.idnetters.co.uk/forums/index.php?topic=23852.0) seem to indicate that this means a user account has taken ownership of the file, however all the files listed `SYSTEM` as the file owner.  I did check a different server that I have not run the installer on, and it does **not** have the lock icon applied to the IIS files.

I have also seen the same lock icon appear on other files that the NSIS installer creates.  For instance, I have a `Web.Config.tpl` file that is processed using the NSIS ReplaceInFile which also appears with the lock icon after the installer finished.
[image: locked web.config file after installer runs]

After I explicitly grant another user account access to the file, the lock icon goes away.

[image: After adding the IUSR to the file]

I run the installer under the local Administrator account on the 2008 R2 server, so I do not get the UAC prompt. Here is the relevant code from the `install.nsi` file

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin

Section "Application" APP_SECTION
   SectionIn RO
   Call InstallApp
SectionEnd

Section "un.Uninstaller Section"
   Delete "$PROGRAMFILES\${PROGRAMFILESDIR}\Uninstall.exe"
   Call un.InstallApp
SectionEnd

Function InstallApp
   File /oname=Web.Config Web.Config.tpl
   !insertmacro ReplaceInFile Web.Config %CONNECTION_STRING% $CONNECTION_STRING
FunctionEnd

Function un.InstallApp
   ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\${REGKEY}" "VirtualDir"    
   NsisIIS::DeleteVDir "$0"
   Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

I have three questions stemming from this incident:

1. How did this happen?
2. How can I fix my installer to prevent it from happening again?
3. How can I repair the permissions on the IIS config files.

Answer (score 1):

The ReplaceInFile macro does a delete and rename dance, it is possible that this messes up the file security information. You could try to work around this by using the macro on a copy of the file you want to modify and then use FileOpen and copy in the new content line by line.

The IIS plugin uses the IIS COM interface, not really sure what could go wrong there. It is probably a good idea to make sure that you don't pass a empty string to NsisIIS::DeleteVDir.

Comment: Any opinion on whether or not using the UAC plugin could help here?

Comment: @Lucas: It would not help, the UAC plugin gives you less privileges, not more, you would not be able to write to system32